# VideoJS font not applied to controls in Firefox 22

Tags: video.js

I did everything according to the setup instructions and got the video.js player play my flv video. The only problem is that the UI is broken in Firefox 22 because the font that is loaded correctly is not applied to the controls. I only see a box with some numbers inside instead of a play button for example.

This works in Chrome correctly.

I double checked with Firebug that the font file is loaded from the server and there are no problems.

Firebug shows this when I inspect the play button:

content: "";

And if I hover font-family I see the VideoJS font sample displayed.

Comment: Can you show us your work on a webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the same origin policy. I was working on a development subdomain but the font was hosted on the main domain and that's why Firefox refused to use it. (Chrome used it)

Comment: Chrome was being naughty.